# Animating window popup on click

Tags: jquery, popup, window

I wish to show a new page which pops out as soon as a link is clicked like in this site when we click at DEMO link given in the link below
http://www.downloadjavascripts.com/Horizontal_Accordion_Panels.aspx
Can anyone guide me how to obtain such a window. I also wish that i could set the opacity of the remaining background content to a low value.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are using Colorbox. You can get it here: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Just look at this example: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html "Outside Webpage (Iframe)".

Cheers

Comment: hmm..thats fine.. But i think that can be easily done using jquery